# How to make it re-enter when user login fail

Tags: java

I have login information in my list. I am trying to match login id and password with list. My code only allow to test correct id and password. If id or password is not matched then my code is not allow me to re enter the id and password.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("*** Welcome back Student ***");

System.out.println("Please enter your Student Id :");
studentID = br.readLine();

System.out.println("Please enter your password :");
password = br.readLine();

// Iterate through list of students to see if we have a match
for (Student student : listOfStudents) {
      if (student.getStudentID().equals(studentID)) {
           if (student.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                loggedInStudent = student;
                break;
           }
      }
}

for (Student student : listOfStudents) {
     if (loggedInStudent != null) {
         System.out.println("Successfully Login");
         break;

     } else if (!student.getStudentID().equals(studentID)) {
         System.out.println("Wrong Student ID, please check and re-enter your Student ID");
         break;
     } else {
         System.out.println("Wrong password, please check and re-enter your password");
         break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to set the code here in a do-while loop. Have a boolean that you can set to true when you need to get out of the loop.

```
   do{
//code you have 
//if condition is met, set boolean to true
}while(!booleanName)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try an validate each entry as you move along. Prompt for the Student ID first then validate it. If it's valid then and only then prompt or the Password related to that Student ID. If it is not valid then allow the User to enter another Student ID before even asking for a password. The same should apply for the password. Once a valid Student ID is acquired, prompt for the password related to that Student ID. If the password is entered incorrectly, then allow the User to try again.

In the runnable demo below, the User can only make three (3) attempts at entering a valid password. This of course can be changed to whatever you like  or removed altogether. Read the Comments in code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StudentLoginDemo {

    final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);  // Auto closed when App closes.
    final String ls = System.lineSeparator();  // Ensure proper newline in OS Terminal
        
    private List<Student> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<>(); // To hold student instances.
    private Student loggedInStudent;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Started this way to avoid the need for statics.
        new StudentLoginDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Some data for the listOfStudents List for the sake of this demo.
        listOfStudents.add(new Student("A1234", "Bill Williams", "foodRunner"));
        listOfStudents.add(new Student("C6032", "Tracey Johnson", "FoodEater"));
        listOfStudents.add(new Student("A8883", "Jane Smith", "SmithRules01"));
        listOfStudents.add(new Student("D3172", "Fred Flintstone", "yabadabadooo"));
        
        System.out.println("*** Welcome Back Student ***" + ls);

        String studentID = "";
        
        while (studentID.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your Student ID (q to quit): -> ");
            studentID = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            // Is quit desired?
            if (studentID.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                System.out.println("Quiting... Bye Bye");
                return;   // Exit method.
            }
            // Validate entry...
            if (!doesIdExist(studentID)) {
                System.out.println("The Student ID (" + studentID 
                                   + ") you entrered can not be found!"
                        + ls + "Try again..." + ls);
                studentID = "";
            }
        }
        
        int passCount = 0;
        String password = "";
        while (password.isEmpty()) {
            passCount++;
            System.out.print("Please enter your password (q to quit): -> ");
            password = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            // Is quit desired?
            if (password.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                System.out.println("Quiting... Bye Bye");
                return;   // Exit method.
            }
            // Validate entry...
            loggedInStudent = doesPasswordExist(studentID, password);
            if (loggedInStudent == null) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Password! (" + password 
                                   + ") Student related password can not be found!"
                        + ls + (passCount < 3 ? "Remember, passwords are case sensitive. "
                        + "Try again..." + ls : ""));
                password = "";
            }
            if (passCount == 3) {
                System.out.println("You have failed to enter a valid Student Password for "
                        + "the" + ls + "Student ID of \"" + studentID + "\" within 3 attempts. "
                        + "Quiting...");
                return;
            }
        }
        
        // If we have passed through the `while` loops then all is successfull.
        String studentName = loggedInStudent.getStudentName();
        System.out.println(ls + "Welcome " + (studentName.isEmpty() ? "Student" : studentName)
                            + ", You have successfully logged in.");
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns boolean true if the supplied Student ID exists within 
     * the listOfStudents List, false if not.<br>
     * 
     * @param id (String) The Student ID. The ID can be alphanumeric. 
     * Not letter case sensitive.<br>
     * 
     * @return (boolean) Boolean true is returned if the ID exists within 
     * the listOfStudents List and false if not.
     */
    private boolean doesIdExist(String id) {
        boolean found = false;
        // Iterate through list of students to see if we have the ID
        for (Student student : listOfStudents) {
            if (student.getStudentID().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns a Student object if the password is valid for the 
     * supplied ID.<br>
     * 
     * @param id (String) The Student ID.<br>
     * 
     * @param passwrd (String) The Password related to the Student ID. 
     * The password is letter case sensitive.<br>
     * 
     * @return (Student) Returns the Student instance related to the Student 
     * ID and Student Password.
     */
    private Student doesPasswordExist(String id, String passwrd) {
        Student stud = null;
        /* Iterate through list of students to see if we have 
           a match to the Student ID and related Password.  */
        for (Student student : listOfStudents) {
            if (student.getStudentID().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                if (student.getPassword().equals(passwrd)) {
                    stud = student;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return stud;
    }
    
    /**
     * Student class: Used here as an inner class for demo purposes only. 
     * This should really be a class file (.java) of its own.
     */
    public class Student {

        private String studentID;
        private String studentName = "";
        private String password;

        // Contructor #1:
        public Student() { }
        
        // Contructor #2:
        public Student(String studentID, String password) {
            this.studentID = studentID;
            this.password = password;
        }
        
        // Contructor #3:
        public Student(String studentID, String studentName, String password) {
            this.studentID = studentID;
            this.studentName = studentName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        
        // Getters & Setters
        public String getStudentID() {
            return studentID;
        }

        public void setStudentID(String studentID) {
            this.studentID = studentID;
        }

        public String getStudentName() {
            return studentName;
        }

        public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
            this.studentName = studentName;
        }
        
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

}
```